# Setting column filter / criteria on query brings up Access' "Enter Parameter" dialogue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've written a query that has a few calculated fields (the values are financial and each field relates to a month of the year) E.g.:

```
Period 1 ALS: [Period 1]-[Period 1 Retention]
Period 2 ALS: [Period 2]-[Period 2 Retention]
Period 3 ALS: [Period 3]-[Period 3 Retention]
```

...and so on up to Period 12.

Then I have a final column that adds up all these "Period X ALS" columns to make a "TotalALS" column. [Period 1 ALS]+[Period 2 ALS]+[Period 3 ALS] ...and so on.

The idea is that I would put ">0" in the criteria of the "TotalALS" column and so end up with a query that filters-out all the records where there no money was calculated.

Problem is, as soon as I put the criteria >0 against the "TotalALS" field, Access asks for a parameter value for each of the "Period X ALS" columns I created before the query will run.

From what I understand, Access asks for a parameter when it can't find something that's referenced in the query. I'm not sure how this can be the case though as the query runs fine when I don't specify any criteria.

I also read that it could be to do with Access misreading the format of the fields. All the source fields are numeric (i.e. [Period 1] and [Period 1 Retention]), so I would assume that the calculated fields would follow the same numeric format.

I ran the Database Documenter on this query and interestingly it was listing my calculated fields under the Query Paramenters group of the report, each with the Type "Text". Not sure how it can think these fields are text though.

To see if this was the issue I tried to explicitly declare my so-called "parameters" i.e, putting this at the top of the SQL:

```SQL
PARAMETERS [Period 1 ALS] IEEEDouble, [Period 2 ALS] IEEEDouble, etc...
```

Although the Database Dcoumenter report shows each of these fields as the numeric format I've now  specified, I'm still getting the "Enter Parameter Value" pop-up when I actually try to run the query.

Slightly abbreviated SQL:

```SQL
SELECT 
[T_FM45_PeriodConversion03-ALS].[Period 1], 
[Period 1]*[Partner Rate]) AS [Period 1 Retention], 
[Period 1]-[Period 1 Retention] AS [Period 1 ALS],
```

The above 3 fields repeated for periods 2 to 12 of the year. Then my TotalALS field:

```SQL
[Period 1 ALS]+[Period 2 ALS]+[Period 3 ALS]+[Period 4 ALS]+[Period 5 ALS]+[Period 6 ALS]+[Period 7 ALS]+[Period 8 ALS]+[Period 9 ALS]+[Period 10 ALS]+[Period 11 ALS]+[Period 12 ALS] AS TotalALS,
```

```SQL
INTO [T_FM45_PeriodConversion04-ALS]
```

```SQL
FROM [T_FM45_PeriodConversion03-ALS] LEFT JOIN Partners ON [T_FM45_PeriodConversion03-ALS].PartnerAbbr = Partners.Abbreviation
```

```SQL
WHERE ((([Period 1 ALS]+[Period 2 ALS]+[Period 3 ALS]+[Period 4 ALS]+[Period 5 ALS]+[Period 6 ALS]+[Period 7 ALS]+[Period 8 ALS]+[Period 9 ALS]+[Period 10 ALS]+[Period 11 ALS]+[Period 12 ALS])>0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your query assigns aliases to field expressions and then attempts to use those aliases in the `WHERE` clause.  Use the unaliased field expression in the `WHERE` clause.

Instead of something like this ...

```sql
SELECT (fld2 - fld1) AS difference
FROM MyTable
WHERE difference > 0;
```

Use this ...

```sql
SELECT (fld2 - fld1) AS difference
FROM MyTable
WHERE (fld2 - fld1) > 0;
```

That pattern exists in your query.  In your `SELECT` list you have ...

```sql
SELECT ..., [Period 1]-[Period 1 Retention] AS [Period 1 ALS], ...
```

Then in the `WHERE` clause, you have ...

```sql
WHERE ((([Period 1 ALS]+ ...
```

The problem is that `[Period 1 ALS]` is an alias, so at the time the db engine evaluates the `WHERE` clause, it doesn't recognize the alias.  Therefore it assumes `[Period 1 ALS]` must be a parameter and asks you to supply a value for that parameter.

Comment: Hi HansUp. It seems to be doing what you recommended already, i.e. it is referencing the full expression of the calculated field rather than than the name of the calculated field: `WHERE ((([Period 1 ALS]+[Period 2 ALS]+[Period 3 ALS] ...etc )>0))`

Comment: Show us your query's SQL ... switch to SQL View, copy the text and paste it into your question.  If this is a really complicated query, please first simplify it to the minimum which illustrates the problem and show us the SQL from that simpler query.

Comment: Beg your pardon, I said it wasn't using the alias, but clearly it is. So the DB engine evaluates the WHERE clause before the SELECT clause? That's rather annoying! So would I need to set my WHERE clause up without reference to any alias created within this query? That's going to be quite long as each [Period X ALS] alias also refers to [Period X Retention], which another aliased field(!) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Attempting to re-use an alias later in a query is troublesome.  In certain situations it works but I don't think it ever works in a `WHERE`.  My first impulse was to suggest you define the aliases in a subquery --- then those alias names would be recognized in the parent (containing) query.  However, I got confused by your SQL and don't understand what you're trying to do.  Maybe you should go back to the drawing board ... submit a question with a brief set of sample input data and show us the output you want from that sample.

Comment: I've written the WHERE clause without reference to any alias and it is a bit long, but it works ok. I'm still quite new to Access, so my approach to certain tasks are probably not always the smartest way of doing something at the moment. Parent/Child queries sounds interesting; I'll look that uo. Thanks again for your help today.

Comment: Aliasing the table names might help reduce the text size of your overall query, although I'm unsure whether it could shorten your current `WHERE` clause: `FROM [T_FM45_PeriodConversion03-ALS] AS p03`  Then you can reference that table elsewhere by just `p03` instead of the long bracketed name.  Although re-using aliased field expressions can be tricky, aliased table names work as you probably expect.